# Facebook sdk v5 revoke token issue

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

How to I revoke the access token? I unset and destroy the session, which works fine to remove the data, but when I log in again, I'd like to be able to log in with a different Facebook account (it automatically logs me in to the account I had previously logged in with).

I've read over the docs but clearly I am missing something. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Log into to your Facebook account and in your settings find a list of authorized apps. Then delete the app's access to your account. This should disable futher autologins.
2. Do it through REST API. You need to send `DELETE` to `PROFILE-ID/permissions` as it is [described in the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking#revokelogin).

Note: You can also use `me` instead of your `id`:

```
# Revoke access of currently logged in user
DELETE /me/permissions

# Or if you want to revoke access for a specific user
DELETE /{user-id}/permissions
```